# Add custom informations to paypal recurring payments

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to make a recurring payment system with paypal on my own website.
People on my website have accounts, and they will pay in order to get more options.

I've a "suscribe" button created with paypal (price, payments intervals etc choosen in paypal). Onclick, my customer is redirected to paypal website in order to continue his purchase. 
This is working, if the payment performed I add options to the user in my database. 
So, there is a recurring payment each months but I have to create a "Cancel" or "Disengagement" button.

This disengagment button have been created too, so onclik the user is redirected to the paypal website to cancel his subscription. 
If the subscription is canceled, paypal send me informations with the IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) to an URL indicate in paypal options (paypal-notification.php).

The problem is that the user isn't redirected to my website after this, so I can't get his session information (id or email indicate in my database) to delete his options in the database.

I think that is possible to add custom options to paypal when a user suscribe at the options. For example, I give the user ID (of my database) to paypal when he is suscribing and Paypal give me back this Id when the user cancel is suscribtion ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

PayPal uses a subscription ID. When you're registering the subscription you can send through a custom ID, normally an order ID but in your case it could be the user ID. So you just add `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id">` to your form, and then the IPN will have that ID in it for every notification, including the cancellation notification.

When the user first subscribes you'll get a subscription started notification from PayPal, at that point you should record the ID given to this subscription by PayPal. It's stored in the `subscr_id` value passed back by PayPal IPN. Then when the user cancels the subscription the notification will have that subscription id, which you can use to identify which user has cancelled their subscription. This would be the better way, rather than relying on the user ID being passed back from PayPal.